# Current Context error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am having trouble calling out Method `Globals.Global.InstantiateBlowerObj();` in public `frmMain()`.  I am getting the error "The name 'Globals.Global.InstantiateBlowerObj' does not exist in the current context."  I have all the classes and methods as public and I cant figure this out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WetVacClient;
using Globals;
using Globals.Global;

namespace Globals
{
    public class Global
    {
        public Blower[] _Blower = new Blower[4];

        public void InstantiateBlowerObj()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                _Blower[i] = new Blower(i);
        }
    }
}


namespace WetVacClient
{

    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {


        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Globals.Global.InstantiateBlowerObj();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make  both the method and _Blower Property Static

```
public static Blower[] _Blower = new Blower[4];

public static void InstantiateBlowerObj()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        _Blower[i] = new Blower(i);
}
```

Otherwise create an intance of Global and call it's instance method (but that's not what you want I think).

```
Globals.Global g=new Globals.Global();
g.InstantiateBlowerObj();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it `static`.

You are trying to access a non-static member in an static context.

```
public static void InstantiateBlowerObj()
{
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            _Blower[i] = new Blower(i);
}
```